# Uitableview different cell

Tags: ios, uitableview

i have this page in which every cell is different , so i am doing this like the code below , but somehow i believe it can be optimized , any ideas , should i use custom cell but if yes then i have to create 12 custom cells , because each cell has entirely different layout

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath

 static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
 UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
 //    if (cell == nil){

 cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
 //    }

  if (indexPath.row==0)
{

UILabel *lbl_label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(15, 7, 200, 25)];
lbl_label.text = @"PRICE";
[lbl_label setFont:NORMAL_LABEL(16)];
[lbl_label setTextColor:UIColorFromRGB(0x565A5C,1.0)];

    UILabel *lbl_price = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(100, 7, 200, 25)];
    lbl_price.text = @"$ 50";
    [lbl_price setFont:NORMAL_LABEL(16)];
    [lbl_price setTextColor:[UIColor grayColor]];
    [lbl_price setTextColor:UIColorFromRGB(0x82898D,1.0)];
    lbl_price.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentRight;

    [cell addSubview:lbl_price];
[cell addSubview:lbl_label];

}
else if (indexPath.row==1)
{

    UILabel *lbl_label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(15, 7, 200, 25)];
    lbl_label.text = @"CUISINE";
    [lbl_label setFont:NORMAL_LABEL(16)];
    [lbl_label setTextColor:UIColorFromRGB(0x565A5C,1.0)];


        UILabel *lbl_price = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(100, 7, 200, 25)];
        lbl_price.text = @"Sushi, Japanese, Arabian";
        [lbl_price setFont:NORMAL_LABEL(16)];
        [lbl_price setTextColor:[UIColor grayColor]];
        [lbl_price setTextColor:UIColorFromRGB(0x82898D,1.0)];
        lbl_price.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentRight;

        [cell addSubview:lbl_price];
    [cell addSubview:lbl_label];

}
else if (indexPath.row==2)
{

    UILabel *lbl_label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(15, 7, 200, 25)];
    lbl_label.text = @"GOOD FOR";
    [lbl_label setFont:NORMAL_LABEL(16)];
    [lbl_label setTextColor:UIColorFromRGB(0x565A5C,1.0)];

        UILabel *lbl_price = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(100,7, 200, 25)];
        lbl_price.text = @"Alcohol, Brunch";
        [lbl_price setFont:NORMAL_LABEL(16)];
        [lbl_price setTextColor:[UIColor grayColor]];
        [lbl_price setTextColor:UIColorFromRGB(0x82898D,1.0)];
        lbl_price.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentRight;

        [cell addSubview:lbl_price];
    [cell addSubview:lbl_label];

cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;

return cell;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

If you like use Custom cell then you can use as per given below.

First, you should register All 12 cells' NIB:
And After Register , you have to handle it in Cell

```
- (void)viewDidLoad{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    static NSString *CellIdentifier1 = @"ContentCell";
    static NSString *CellIdentifier2 = @"SpaceCell";

    UINib *nib = [UINib nibWithNibName:@"CellViewNIBName" bundle:nil];
    [self.tableView registerNib:nib forCellReuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier1];

    nib = [UINib nibWithNibName:@"CellSpaceNIBName" bundle:nil];
    [self.tableView registerNib:nib forCellReuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier2];

    self.contentView.hidden = YES;
    [self loadData];
}

- (UITableViewCell*)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath      *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier1 = @"ContentCell";
    static NSString *CellIdentifier2 = @"SpaceCell";

    // Space Cell
    if (indexPath.row % 2 == 1) {
        CellSpace *cell = (CellSpace *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier2];
        return cell;
    }

    // Content cell
    else {
        CellView *cell = (CellView *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier1];
        // Configure cell
        return cell;
    }
}
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // Space cell's height
    if (indexPath.row % 2 == 1) {
        return 20.0f;
    }

    // Content cell's height
    else {
        return 80.0f;
    }
}
```